# Move web in SharePoint 2013 Foundation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

Is there a way to move a web in SharePoint 2013 Foundation?

I am aware that it is possible using "Content and structure" in the Server edition, but I am asking about Foundation.

I am also aware that it is possible if we are talking about an entire site collection, but I am asking about a single subweb.

So, for example it could be:
 Move `http://sharepoint.server.com/web` to `http://sharepoint.server.com/another-web/web`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [export](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895(v=office.15).aspx) & [import](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613(v=office.15).aspx) powershell.

```
Export-SPWeb "http://sharepoint.server.com/web" -Path "site export.cmp"
```

then run the import process:

```
Import-SPWeb "http://sharepoint.server.com/another-web/web" -Path export.cmp -UpdateVersions Overwrite
```

You can also try to use Save as template options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Import and export cmdlets in SharePoint 2013

```
Export-SPWeb http://site -Path "site export.cmp"

Import-SPWeb http://site -Path export.cmp -UpdateVersions Overwrite
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee906557(v=office.15).aspx